# ad failed to load No ad config. for admob flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart, admob, adsense

I try to use flutter `AdMob` in test mode on my phone , I got this error:

```
 Ad failed to load: LoadAdError(code: 3, domain: 
 com.google.android.gms.ads, message: No ad config., responseInfo: 
 ResponseInfo(responseId: null, mediationAdapterClassName: , 
 adapterResponses: [], loadedAdapterResponseInfo: null), responseExtras: {})
 ad failed to load No ad config.
```

I add my phone as a test device , also I was banned from google adsense before , is there any solution for this.

I add my phone as a test device , sign the app , use test id for all ads , add test id in manefist file.

Comment: The error "No ad config" means that the AdMob server did not return any ads to be displayed. This could be related to being banned from Google AdSense, but it may also be because of incorrect configurations, could you provide more details?

Comment: thanks for your interest , but what details you need

Comment: is it possible to reactive my adsense account ? also  I make a new account why it not show the ads?